# How to test an Alpha version of a Google Assistant app

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

I have deployed an Alpha version of my app and supplied the email address of a tester and received the opt-in link the user can use to access the Alpha app. In typical fashion, Google gives no instructions for the user, who clicks on the link and promptly gets an error message that no Google or Stackflow search throws any light on.

A further Stackflow search reveals a complex procedure for an Android phone involving copying the opt-in link to Google Notes, pressing on it, and then taking the option to open the Google Assistant app. It would be difficult to find a better way to discourage testers.

Also, this only opens the app on an Android phone. No mention of how the 20 testers can access the Alpha app on Google Home or Nest Mini. Frustrating when the app is specifically designed for use on Google Home or Nest Mini and not on a phone. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: If you can provide more information about the error being shown when the opt-in link is clicked, that will help us be able to help you further.

Comment: Also, please verify the instructions on [getting feedback](https://developers.google.com/assistant/console/releases#get-feedback) to ensure your testers are opting-in first on their phones to then have the testing available on all of their devices.

Comment: This will have to wait until I get some alpha testes with Home/Nest. Maybe in a couple of weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Users need to opt-in to the alpha program on the phone by following the link. (They shouldn't need to copy it, but they will likely need to open it in an actual browser such as chrome.)

Once they have opted in, however, it will be usable on any device linked to the same account on your approved list and that they used to accept.